# SwiftUI GroupBoxStyle fill height

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom `GroupBoxStyle` where I would like to add a think coloured line to its left edge that takes the entire height of the GroupedBox. This GroupedBox is then used in rows in a `VStack`

Here in blue is the `content` of the GroupBox, in yellow is that line I want to add. The blue content can be any view.

[image]

In my my current implementation (see below) but the problem is that the vertical line does not take all the height of the GroupBox

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 8) {
                    GroupBox {
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Hello")
                                Text("Hello")
                                Text("Hello")
                                Text("Hello")

                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }

                    GroupBox {
                        Color.blue
                            .frame(height: 50)
                    }
                }
                // try to uncomment this
//                .padding(8)
            }
            .groupBoxStyle(StandardGroupBoxStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("My Group", displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
}

public struct StandardGroupBoxStyle: GroupBoxStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.yellow
                .frame(width: 5)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)

            VStack {
                configuration
                    .content
            }
            .border(Color.green)
            Spacer()
        }
        .border(Color.red)
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This implementation and example creates this (note the yellow not taking the entire height of the row.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution (I kept original extra modifiers, but assume they are for debug purpose). Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
public struct StandardGroupBoxStyle: GroupBoxStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            configuration.content
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .border(Color.green)      // << debug?
            Spacer()                     // << debug?
        }
        .overlay(Color.yellow.frame(width: 5), alignment: .leading)
        .border(Color.red)              // << debug?
    }
}
```

Comment: that works as expected. I wonder why my solution does not though. Any ideas?